# Shiny app Error chartSeries requires an xtsible object?

Tags: r, shiny, quantmod

I have following basic code with shiny:

```
library(quantmod); library(shiny);

ui <- fluidPage(

  textInput("Symbol","Assign_Symbol","GOOG"),
  dateRangeInput("Date","Assing_Date", start = Sys.Date() - 20, end = Sys.Date()),

  plotOutput("Chart")

)

server <- function(input, output) {
  envSymbol <- new.env()
  Sym <- "Sym"

  envSymbol[[Sym]] <- reactive({
    as.xts(getSymbols(input$Symbol, auto.assign = FALSE))
  })

  output$Chart <- renderPlot({

    chartSeries(
      envSymbol[[Sym]],
      theme = chartTheme("white"),
      type = "line",
      subset = paste(input$Date, collapse = "::")
    )

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The window comes up with symbol and date as expected, but in the chart section I always get `Error: chartSeries requires an xtsible object`

I don't know shiny and this is from code samples online. I have found longer more complicated samples, but I still get the same xtsible object error.

Can somebody tell me what I am missing?

Comment: You missed the empty parantheses for your chart object in the `chartSeries` function ! Should be : `envSymbol[[Sym]]()`

Comment: You are exactly right, I did that and it works perfectly. Please post it as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reactive expression `envSymbol[[Sym]]` is technically a function. So to call it you must call it with parenthesis ( `envSymbol[[Sym]]()` ) when calling `chartSeries`. For more detailed information have a look at [this video](https://vimeo.com/rstudioinc/review/131218530/212d8a5a7a/#t=63m40s). (should start at around 1h03m)